# How to ignore specific tables/stored procedures/views in SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am new to SSDT and I am trying to find a way to ignore some tables when I am comparing schema using the ssdt UI in Visual Studio. Is there a way to do this in SSDT. I think it is possible via command line but wanted to know if I can create a .scmp file with only those tables that I want to compare.

Comment: whats the reason you want to ignore the tables?   ie, whats the underlying reason for the difference in schema?  maybe there is another way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also tried to find such an option, but failed.
You can uncheck some items in the comparison result and save the comparison. In this case, they will stay unchecked the next time you run the comparison.

Comment: This is not true since next time there is a new table ssdt doesn't ignore those unchecked tables anymore.